# How to debug in AS3 only project in Flex...?

Tags: apache-flex, debugging, actionscript

I am trying to build a AS3 only project in Flex....I have tried debug mode, but seems like it takes so long to compile....I can't use trace or check variables...Are there anyway to do debug?? Thanks for the help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Flash Player have you installed, you need the debugger version. Check your browser , some browsers like Chrome for instance , come with Flash Player bundled in , but this isn't the version you need. You can also check your application properties, particularly the Run/Debug Settings. 
Last but not least, you could also watch this Lee Brimelow tutorial, about using MonsterDebugger
http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=109